# Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Xml_Security' not found lib/Zend/Locale/Data.php

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Xml_Security' not found in lib/Zend/Locale/Data.php on line 164
```

After upgrading magento from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.1, I'm getting this error.

I simply extracted all files from zip. I deleted var/cache and var/session.

What might be the problem, please?

Comment: Can you re-copy your files. Do you have APC running? Please give more information about how you performed your upgrade.

Comment: Please check if you have Compilation enabled (`admin panel -> System -> Tools -> Compilation`). If yes - run compilation process again.  
As a final try - you can try to uncomment `require_once 'Zend/Xml/Security.php';` in `lib/Zend/Locale/Data.php` on line 29.

Comment: I had to comment out all on line 29. `/** @see Zend_Xml_Security #require_once 'Zend/Xml/Security.php';
*/` I hope it isn't safety issue, is it?

Answer (score 1):

It happens also to me. By accident new files were not uploaded ( only modified ). Please make sure, if file  `lib/Zend/Xml/Security.php` exists.